# Proving that Euler characteristic is locally constant; don't understand how we reduce to a Serre twist...

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading a proof (in chapter 24 of Ravi's notes) of the Euler characteristic being locally constant in flat families. I am confused about the following reduction:

Let $F$ be some coherent sheaf on $P^n_A$. Then to show that $\chi(F)$ is locally constant, it suffices to show this property for $F(m)$ (serre twist). I don't understand why this is valid, though I understand how this reduction is vital to the rest of the argument. What am I misunderstanding?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is because the map $\mathbb{Z} \ni n \mapsto \chi(F(n))$
is a polynomial in $n$ (Hartshorne exercise III.5.2).

So if you can prove that: given $p ,q \in spec(A)$ there is an $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $\chi(F_{|X_p}(n))=\chi(F_{|X_q}(n))$ then they are
the same polynomial so also $\chi(F_{|X_p})=\chi(F_{|X_q})$.

Comment: Thanks, this is definately it! I kept thinking - what is the relationship between the Euler characteristics of the Serre twists ... of course it is that they are tied together because they are the values of the Hilbert polynomial of F. This whole proof of this theorem (in Ravis notes) is filled with these kind of beautiful reductions ... "the rising sea" indeed. Thanks for your answer!